# Distribution of number of people having money M in their bank account

Tags: data-request, tool-request

Not sure whether to post this here or have my post migrated to personal finance and money SE, please recommend.

I would like to know, where I can find, for each country, the graph of the following data distribution:

On the x-axis, money amount, in thousands dollars or other currency.

On the y-axis, for graphs (a), (b), and (c), number of people, having, for the given year, on average, (a) that amount of money in their bank accounts, (b) that amount of money invested in financial instruments, and (c) that amount of money in property such as real estate or car assets.

This would allow you to assess in full detail your financial situation relative to that of others.

Thanks.

Comment: This question seems on-topic for this site, but it might be more successful on personal finance and money SE. Financial advisers are exactly the kind of people who would know where to find this data. Also, this seems like it would be proprietary data, not open data.

Comment: Can you please migrate my post to personal finance and money SE or economics SE? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a personal finance and money mod - I've closed the question there (and hence rejected the migration) because requests for off-site resources are off-topic for us.

Comment: So where should I post it. On Economics SE? Can you please migrate my question? Can you please migrate my question to the most appropriate site?